# Powershell: Get the current time with w32tm

Tags: powershell, time

My task is to get the current time with the w32time service from a Windows 2016 Server, and compare it to the time showed on this server. What I find online about this service is synchronising, and doing more complicated stuff, but I simply need the "official" time in the simplest form, so I can compare the two, and check if there is more than a few seconds of difference between the two.
I can get some useful info with

```
w32tm /stripchart /computer:time.windows.com /samples:1 /dataonly
```

Which output has the line

```
09:59:38, +00.1323527s
```

Is this the difference between the NTP server and my server? Is there a more straightforward way to achieve what I intend to do, or should I just crop this line out the output, and use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](https://www.sikich.com/insight/correct-time-settings-more-in-depth-using-w32tm/) the `+00.1323527` value you see is the actual offset between local time and the target computer time. If you’re seeing differences in the 0.00* range for actual offset, you can be highly confident that you have the correct system time. Anything with less than a second offset is reasonably good as well.

You can strip the time difference out like:

```
$currentTime, $timeDifference = (& w32tm /stripchart /computer:time.windows.com /samples:1 /dataonly)[-1].Trim("s") -split ',\s*'

$timeDifference

# or if you rather have a numeric value than a string, cast it to Double:
[double]$timeDifference
```

Comment: Offset is the word I was looking for. Thank you for your straightforward answer!